# Detect windows registry events using java

Tags: java, windows, registry

How do I detect `RegOpenKey`, `RegSetValue`, and `RegCloseKey` events using Java?

Programs that I have tried only allowed me to read the value of key in the registry, delete a key, or create it. I want to detect if any process has made a change to the registry.

Answer (score 1):

One way might be to hook the windows kernel functions such as [ZwEnumerateKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566447%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and it's cousins.

I don't believe java can do this on it's own, but you might be able to write a module in C/C++ and expose it to java via [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html).

There is open source software which already does the monitoring you want in C++, so the major challenge would be creating the SWIG interface to java.

A second option might be to have java `Runtime.exec` a [procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) with a `/backingfile` option (to save output to a log) and then parsing that log from java to extract the information you want.